# Some sheet music to decode

Tags: word, cipher, music

Find the word that was encoded in this sheet music:

[image: score]

(No instrument is required)

Comment: I've try to edit the tag without success: it's not a cipher  but an encode-message.

Comment: What’s the difference between that and a cipher, for us uninitiated?

Comment: As both are synonymous and encoded-message has only 14 posts, it could have been converted into cipher

Comment: There is no key involved. I may be wrong. My english is not so good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the word we're looking for is

> MUSE

obtained by

> treating each bar as a Morse code letter: minims for - and crotchets for . .

Comment: That's the sound of a mystery solved ^_^